# Bash incrementation without breaking sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to place ordinal number before each line with `{`.

Here is code

```
   #!/bin/bash
   i=1;
   sed '
   /{/ i\
   'i++'
   ' text.sub
```

I tried `i=$(i+1)` and more, but it echoes "i=2" or something;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk '/{/ { print ++i };1' File
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use `ORS` instead of hardcoding `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

It'll be simpler with awk:

```
$ cat text.sub
foo
{bar
baz
{qux

$ awk '/{/ {print ++i} {print}' text.sub
foo
1
{bar
baz
2
{qux
```

If you need to do arithmetic in the shell, use `$(( i++ ))` arithmetic expansion syntax